# Javascript: Count and sort number of each type in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a dataset like this

```
const data = [
{category: 'fish'; age: '10'; color: 'red'; },
{category: 'fish'; age: '9'; color: 'red'; },
{category: 'fish'; age: '8'; color: 'blue'; },
{category: 'fish'; age: '7'; color: 'blue'; },
{category: 'birds'; age: '10'; color: 'red'; },
{category: 'birds'; age: '9'; color: 'red'; },
{category: 'birds'; age: '8'; color: 'blue'; },
{category: 'birds'; age: '7'; color: 'blue'; },
]
```

but I need to be able to count and sort them in a single function similar to..

```
const count = (data: any) => {
 // How to count how many of each category without hard coding fish or birds
 return [
    {category: 'fish'; total: 4}, 
    {category: 'birds'; total: 4},
 ]
}
const summary = count(data);
```

and sort them...

```
const sort = (data: any, onlyShow: string, sortBy: string | number, ascDesc: number) => {
 // How to only show the birds and then sort by age in ascending order
 return [
    {category: 'birds'; age: '7'; color: 'red'; },
    {category: 'birds'; age: '8'; color: 'red'; },
    {category: 'birds'; age: '9'; color: 'blue'; },
    {category: 'birds'; age: '10'; color: 'blue'; },
]
}
const sortedData = sort(data, 'birds', 'age', '-1')
```

Comment: check this out https://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. Also, please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post: [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
{category: 'fish', age: '10', color: 'red' },
{category: 'fish', age: '9', color: 'red' },
{category: 'fish', age: '8', color: 'blue'},
{category: 'fish', age: '7', color: 'blue' },
{category: 'birds', age: '10', color: 'red' },
{category: 'birds', age: '9', color: 'red' },
{category: 'birds', age: '8', color: 'blue' },
{category: 'birds', age: '7', color: 'blue' },
];

const count = (data) => {
 // How to count how many of each category without hard coding fish or birds
  return data.reduce((t, v) => {
    let f = t.find(i => i.category == v.category);
    if(f){
      f.total++;
    }else{
      t.push({"category": v.category, "total": 1});
    }
    return t;
  }, []);
}
const summary = count(data);
console.log(summary);

const sort = (data, onlyShow, sortBy, ascDesc) => {
  // How to only show the birds and then sort by age in ascending order
  return data
            .filter(v => v.category == onlyShow)
            .sort((a, b) => (+ascDesc) ? a[sortBy] - b[sortBy] : b[sortBy] - a[sortBy])

}
const sortedData = sort(data, 'birds', 'age', '-1');
console.log(sortedData)
```

Comment: If `ascDesc` values are 1 and -1, you can simplify it to: `ascDesc * (a[sortBy] - b[sortBy])`

Answer (score 0):

Universal filtering and sorting. Because of age is text, "10" will be less than "7", "8" and etc, if you want numeric sorting - convert text to numbers

```
const filterAndSort = (data, filter = {}, sort = {}) => {
   const filterArr = Object.entries(filter)
   const sortArr = Object.entries(sort)
   const dataFiltered = filterArr.length
      ? data.filter(v => filterArr.every(([key, value]) => v[key] == value))
      : data

   const dataSorted = sortArr.length 
      ? dataFiltered.sort((a, b) => {
            const [sortKey, direction] = 
                  sortArr.find(([key, _]) => a[key] != b[key])  || []
            if (!sortKey) return 0 
            return (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey] ? -1 : 1) * (direction == 'desc' ? -1 : 1)    
         })   
      : dataFiltered

   return dataSorted
} 

const data = [
   {category: 'fish', age: '10', color: 'red', },
   {category: 'fish', age: '9', color: 'red', },
   {category: 'fish', age: '8', color: 'blue', },
   {category: 'fish', age: '7', color: 'blue', },
   {category: 'birds', age: '10', color: 'red', },
   {category: 'birds', age: '9', color: 'red', },
   {category: 'birds', age: '8', color: 'blue', },
   {category: 'birds', age: '7', color: 'blue', },
]

var res = filterAndSort(data, {category: 'birds'}, {age: "asc"})
console.log(res)
```